# Finding the missing value in an 'almost-ratio-table' (rank-1 matrix approximation with 1 missing value)

Tags: missing-data, matrix, linear-algebra

#### Motivation:

I have a 4x4 table of positive values (let's call it $A$) with the bottom right value missing ($A_{44}$ is not defined), and I think/assume the table is a ratio-table with just a little bit of noise.
My goal is to find the missing value.

#### Mathematical formulation:

The way I am seeing this problem is approximating $A$ with a rank-1 matrix $P$, the error used being the usual sum of errors squared but only on the known values. I want to find the best rank-1 approximation, or just $P_{44}$ the prediction for the missing value according to this approximation.

#### What I am looking for:

I am not even sure what to do with a 2x3 matrix with one value missing, surely it can't be that complicated ? An answer to this would be of huge help to me.

Even with a 2x2, the cross-product could explode if the noise brings $A_{11}$ close to $0$, which makes me think the approximation by a rank-1 matrix is not the way to go... Maybe this approach is not the best one, any alternative way to view this problem could also be really helpful.

In general, any way to make an OK prediction on the missing value would make a good answer.

#### What I found:

If we knew all the values, we could use the 1-truncated SVD as the best approximation, but here we can't because of the missing value. Maybe I should just guess at random, use the 1-truncated SVD, repeat 2 or 3 times and be done ?

I searched a bit online but only found about complicated algorithms for low-rank matrix approximations with most of the values missing, I am looking for a simpler and more explicit solution.

At some point, I thought that the missing value predicted by the best rank-1 approximation can be found by taking the mean of all "cross-multiplications" as shown below,

$$P_{44} =? ~\frac{1}{9} \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{A_{i4}A_{4j}}{A_{ij}}$$

but it looks clearly wrong because the noise could induce a division by 0 or by a tiny number resulting in a huge prediction. After some testing, it does not depend only on the cross products, for example multiplying the first column on a 2x3 changes the value of $P_{23}$ the prediction for the missing value according to the best 1-rank approximation

#### Other comments

I studied lots of math and computer science, but first question here, maybe you can suggest some formulation/presentation changes and also some tags ?

Comment: I thought about it more, tried with a geometric mean of all cross-products, then after some testing on a 2x3 matrix with one value missing I found that the prediction does not depend only on the cross products.

Comment: This is a matrix completion problem, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=matrix+completion+answers%3A1

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I understand that there are answers to the more general case of matrix completion, but the answers are complicated and also there is not "one good way to do it". I want to get an understanding of this simpler problem if possible, also I thought it was an easy way of predicting some values efficiently.